# Контейнеризация laravel-echo-server

Tags: laravel, docker, socket.io, redis, laravel-echo

Оборачиваю уже рабочий проект в docker контейнеры и столкнулся с проблемой laravel-echo-server. Я добавил установку его в Dockerfile, но на фронте не происходит коннекта.

Для контейнеризации использую docker-compose, с таким конфигом:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: wex_redis
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    networks:
      - wex-network

  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/containers/app/Dockerfile
    working_dir: /app
    container_name: wex_app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_HOST=database
    networks:
      - wex-network

  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/containers/web/Dockerfile
    working_dir: /app
    container_name: wex_web
    ports:
      - 8082:80
      - 6001:6001
    networks:
      - wex-network

  database:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: wex_db
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE:-wex}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 33062:3306
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    networks:
      - wex-network

networks:
  wex-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
  redis_data:
```

То есть за фронт отвечает контейнер web. В нем у меня устанавливаются css, js зависимости, сам laravel-echo-server и nginx. Вот докерфайл оттуда:

```
FROM node:10-alpine as build

WORKDIR /app

# Load dependencies
COPY ./package*.json ./yarn.lock ./
COPY ./webpack.mix.js ./
RUN yarn install

COPY ./resources/assets /app/resources/assets
COPY ./public/assets /app/public/assets

# Build
RUN yarn run production

# Laravel-echo-server
RUN yarn global add --prod --no-lockfile laravel-echo-server \
    && yarn cache clean

EXPOSE 6001

CMD ["laravel-echo-server", "start"]

# NGINX
FROM nginx:alpine

EXPOSE 80

COPY ./docker/containers/web/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./public /app/public
COPY --from=build /app/public/assets /app/public/assets
```

Настройки laravel-echo-server:

```
{
  "authHost": "http://localhost",
  "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
  "clients": [],
  "database": "redis",
  "databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {},
    "sqlite": {
      "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
    }
  },
  "devMode": true,
  "host": null,
  "port": "6001",
  "protocol": "http",
  "socketio": {},
  "sslCertPath": "",
  "sslKeyPath": "",
  "sslCertChainPath": "",
  "sslPassphrase": "",
  "subscribers": {
    "http": true,
    "redis": true
  },
  "apiOriginAllow": {
    "allowCors": false,
    "allowOrigin": "",
    "allowMethods": "",
    "allowHeaders": ""
  }
}
```

Подключение осущесвляется так:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
```

Порты проброшены, сервер установлен, редис тоже есть. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Ну так в чем была проблема?